# Remove for loop from query

Tags: mysql, for-loop, sql-update

So suppose I have a simple query like below; (its an example, I know that is not proper syntax, but the logic stays the same).

```
for(let i=1; i<len; i++){
    UPDATE table1 
    SET table1.col1 = i 
    WHERE table1.id = arr[i] 
}
```

I want to avoid doing 10 or 20 queries, so I was wondering how to remove the for, perhaps something like

```
UPDATE table1 
SET table1.col1 = ? #<<how to add the increment here.>>
WHERE table1.id IN (arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the array into a `String` of comma separated values and use it in the query.

How you convert array into `String` of such values depends on which language you are using in the application, e.g.:

- [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599917/implode-an-array-into-a-comma-separated-string-from-mysql-query) an example of how to do it in php
- [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622974/convert-string-to-comma-separated-string-in-java) an example of how to do it in Java

Comment: My problem is not how to include the arr in the IN. I am trying to increase the col1 by 1 for every element in the arr.